# Programmatically create tables with jQuery and dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, datatables

I am using [dataTables](https://datatables.net/) to render a table programmatically on a Django web app:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dynamic0").html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" id="peak_table_0"></table>');
    $('#peak_table_0').dataTable( {
        "aaData": {{ table_data|safe }},
        "aoColumns": {{ table_headings|safe }}
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dynamic0"></div>
```

I am going to have many similar tables, where only the data will change, so I would like to automate the table creation. I have tried to put the jQuery initializers in a loop, but in this case the tables don't render:
**jQuery**

```
$("div1").each(function(index) {
    var table_id = "peak_table_" + index
    $(this).html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" id="'+table_id+'"></table>');

    $(table_id).dataTable( {
        "aaData": {{ table_data|safe }},
        "aoColumns": {{ table_headings|safe }}
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div1 id="dynamic0"></div1>
<div1 id="dynamic1"></div1>
```

I'm guessing the selectors are not identified properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works. It was missing the '#' in table_id.

```
$("div1").each(function(index){
      var table_id = "peak_table_"+index;
      $(this).html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" id="'+table_id+'"></table>');
      $("#"+table_id).dataTable( {
          "aaData": {{ table_data|safe }},
          "aoColumns": {{ table_headings|safe }}
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
div1
```

To

```
div
```

I have a hunch jQuery in the DOM chokes because it is not a valid HTML tag.

Comment: But in that case it's going to loop through all div tags, right?